# How to increment for a specific in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfFGu.png) Like in my sample image, below, I want to increase or decrease the quantity by clicking the button for a single list item. If I increase the counter in setState (), its increment in each item in the list. I need help with this, especially managing a specific list item in Flutter Flutter.

```
     Container(
    height: 500.0,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children:
            List.generate(userData == null ? 0 : userData.length, (index) {
          return Container(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 700,
                child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(
                          "${userData[index]["image"]}",
                          width: 300,
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: IconButton(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                                      size: 35.0),
                                  onPressed: _decrementCount),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 20.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                child: Text(
                                  _counter.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: IconButton(
                                color: Colors.orange,
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle,
                                    size: 35.0),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _incrementCount(userData[index]);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 20.0,
                          child: Text(
                            "${userData[index]["libelle"]}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],

                     
                    ))),
          );
        })),
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a separate Stateful class for your List item.

Like this

```
List.generate(2, (index) => MyCustomWidget(
         user[index]
       ))



  class MyCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   final user;
   const MyCustomWidget({Key? key,required this.user}) : super(key:key);
    
   @override
   _MyCustomWidgetState createState() => _MyCustomWidgetState();
    
      
  }
    
    class _MyCustomWidgetState extends State<MyCustomWidget> {
     
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       
        return Container(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 700,
                child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(
                          "${widget.user["image"]}",
                          width: 300,
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: IconButton(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                                      size: 35.0),
                                  onPressed: _decrementCount),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 20.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                child: Text(
                                  _counter.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: IconButton(
                                color: Colors.orange,
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle,
                                    size: 35.0),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _incrementCount(userData[index]);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 20.0,
                          child: Text(
                            "${widget.user["libelle"]}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],

                     
                    ))),
          );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

set some

```dart
conditions  ?  Image.network(
                          "${userData[index]["image"]}",
                          width: 300,
                          height: 100,
                        ), :  Image.network(
                          "${userData[index]["image"]}",
                          width: 400,
                          height: 250,
                        ),
```

So if condition true then it's display like first one other wise take second one